Find and delete directories matching a particular naming pattern
I need to clear certain cache from within the directory C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\1C\1cv8
The cache is stored in different child directories which follow the same naming format.
For example:
????-????-????-????-????????????

The ? above is used to represent one character.
I tried many different methods such as:
@FOR /D %%j in ("C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\1C\1cv8\????????-????-????-????-????????????") do rd /s /q "%%j"

But nothing seems to be working. Anyone have a guess of what I could use?

FYI, the ? wildcard in the above case means any 0 or 1 character, not any 1 character.

Maybe try something like this to get the exact pattern of the directory names you want. for /f "delims=" %%G in ('dir /ad /b ^|findstr /RC:"^........-....-....-....-............$" 2^>nul') do echo %%G

You have omitted \local from your target directoryname

The syntax of your one-liner seems to be correct.

Doublecheck your wildcard pattern matches the actual folder names
Remove the leading @, then you should get an error message which may help debugging
Check you have the needed permissions/rights to delete these folders
Is the corresponding software still running? The folders could be locked since the cache folders are still in use

